# Close button of terminal showing this way

Tags: gnome-terminal, button

Suddenly my terminal started showing wrong symbols   instead of close, maximize and minimize buttons. Software Updater is not opening. The right corner is blank. The buttons are there, but they're not showing properly.

[image]

Before this happened I ran the command:

```
sudo apt install adms
```

Comment: Suddenly?  What were you doing before this happened?

Comment: What is your version of Ubuntu? Have you tried to upgrade or change python?

Comment: Did you change the theme? Or did you perhaps remove some software which may have removed other important packages? If so, try re-installing the desktop with `sudo apt update ; sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop^` (the caret `^` on the end is important)

Comment: i just installed adms using sudo apt install adms and then it turned like this

Comment: What's the output of `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`?